# In what folder/directory does Minio store its objects/files on local disk?

Tags: minio

I'm running a [Minio](https://minio.io/) instance on my local machine, on http://localhost:9000. I created a bucket called `foo`, and uploaded a single file `test.txt` to it.

Since this Minio instance is running on my local machine, where is the "uploaded" binary `test.txt` file actually stored in my local filesystem? That is, is it possible to locate this `test.txt` file in a folder somewhere using the GUI filesystem browser? For example, `/Users/myusername/some/hidden/folder/minio/buckets/foo/test.txt`

I looked through [the docs](https://docs.minio.io/docs/minio-client-complete-guide) and it only has information about using the `mc` command via `mc ls` to view the files in the "remote" Minio machine via the command line. This is not what I'm looking for, I want to see under what folder the `test.txt` file actually resides on my local machine. Is this possible, or am I forced to only view an abstraction of the `test.txt` through the `mc` command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file is stored in the mount you pass to start minio server.

For example if you started minio by minio server /tmp, create a bucket foo, and upload object bar.txt. The file will be present at /tmp/foo/bar.txt